# How to urlencode an Actionscript ByteArray

Tags: actionscript-3, oauth, binary, arrays

I need up upload urlencoded binary data to tumblr.

this is what I'm currently trying:

```
            baseString.params = 'data[0]=' + URLEncoding.encode(byte.toString()).replace('~','%257E');
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: What's wrong with that? It looks like it should work…

Comment: I get a 'Not Authorized' response from Tumblr.

Comment: And are you sure it's your URL encoding that's the issue and not something else?

Comment: yes, I swapped out the line above with baseString.params = 'body=test'; which is the field needed for a text post and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Can you post the encoded version of the string them? Also, `'data[0]'` seems a bit odd — are you sure that's the correct parameter name? Also, could unicode have anything to do with it? (I don't remember how `ByteArray.toString()` handles that…)

Comment: This is what I'm getting from my code:
%25C3%25BF%25C3%2598%25C3%25BF%25C3%25A0%250%2510JFIF%250%251%252%250%250d%250d%250%250%25C3%25BF%25C3%25AC%250%2511Ducky%250%251%250%254%250%250%250d%250%250%25C3%25BF%25C3%25AE%250%25EAdobe%250d%25C3%2580%250%250%250%251%25C3%25BF%25C
It is the first few lines of the image file.
Here is the result from a python script that successfully uploads the same file.
%FF%D8%FF%E0%00%10JFIF%00%01%02%00%00d%00d%00%00%FF%EC%00%11Ducky%00%01%00%04%00%00%00d%00%00%FF%EE%00%0EAdobe%00d%C0%00%00%00%01%FF%DB%00%84%00%01%01%01%01%01%01%01%01
again, only the first lines.

Comment: also, I'm sure that 'data[0]' is correct, here is python code that works. multiple photos are able to be uploaded which would be 'data[0]', 'data[1]', etc

https://gist.github.com/1198576

here is how toString() works, as from Adobe's LiveDocs:

Converts the byte array to a string. If the data in the array begins with a Unicode byte order mark, the application will honor that mark when converting to a string. If System.useCodePage is set to true, the application will treat the data in the array as being in the current system code page when converting.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, first, it looks like some crazy things are going on with your url encoding. The sample you posted above seems to be double encoded:

```
>>> x = unescape("%25C3%25BF%25C3%2598%25C3")
>>> x
"%C3%BF%C3%98%C3"
>>> unescape(x)
"Ã¿ÃÃ"
```

Second, you shouldn't be using `ByteArray.toString()` if the `ByteArray` contains binary data. Instead, if I recall correctly, you should use `ba.readMultiByte(ba.bytesAvailable, "latin1")` which will return a string containing the raw bytes.

Third, I feel like your `URLEncoding` class is suspect. Instead, you can just use the `escape` (and `unescape`) builtins:

```
>>> escape("\12")
"%0A"
```

Comment: Downvoter: would you mind explaining yourself so I can improve my future questions?